# Creating Schema in Node/MongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

So, I am just starting with Node/Mongo db and typescript, and I am kind of stuck in creating a Schema for this nested JSON Database. I have started something and, I would like to know if I am on the right track. So please if anyone would help me it would be great. Thanks in Advance

Data

```
[{
   "a_class":[
   {    
    "brand":"A-class",
    "id":"1",
    "year":"2015"
    "price":"12665"
    ...
    "engine_spec":{
     ...
     }
     ...
      }]

}
]
```

Interfaces

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
export default interface ICars extends Document {
   a_class: BrandList[],
}


interface BrandList {
 brand: string;
 id:number;
 year:number;
 main_image: string;
 price:number;
 transmission:string;
 fuel_type:string;
 seating_capacity:number;
 engine:number;
 engine_specs:Specs;
 volume_weights:Volume;
 performance: Performance
 images_interior: Interior
 images_exterior: Exterior
}

interface Specs {
    power:number;
    power_per_litre:number;
    torque:number;
    fuel_system:number
}

interface Volume {
    max_weights:number;
    fuel_tank:number
}


interface Performance {
    acceleration:number;
    maximum_speed:number;
    fuel_urban:number;
    fuel_extra_urban:number
    fuel_combined:number
}

interface Interior {
    image_one:string;
    image_two:string;
    image_three:string;
    image_four:string;
}

interface Exterior {
    image_one:string;
    image_two:string;
    image_three:string;
    image_four:string;
}
```

Schema

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

import ICars from '../interfaces/cars'

const CarsSchema: Schema = new Schema({

  a_class:Array,
  brand: String,
  year:Number,
})

export default mongoose.model<ICars>('Cars', CarsSchema);
```

Get Route, So when I try to get all the data through postman, it is not allowing me, it is saying that the route is not being found 404. I have imported it to the server.js `import carsRouter from './routes/cars'; router.use('./cars',carsRouter )`, I don't know where the error could be

```
import express from 'express'
import Cars from '../models/cars'

const router = express();


router.get('/cars', (req:any, res:any )=>{
    Cars.find()
    .then(car=> res.json(car))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json(`Error: ${err}`))
})

 export=router
```

Comment: I think the problem is `export=router`. According to es6 `export` documentation, there has not syntax for `export=something` like this. For more information, please reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export?retiredLocale=vi
Please try using `export default router` instead of `export=router`

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to mongoose document, we should avoid extending mongoose `Document`.

> This approach works, but we recommend your document interface not
> extend Document. Using extends Document makes it difficult for
> Mongoose to infer which properties are present on query filters, lean
> documents, and other cases.
>
> We recommend your document interface contain the properties defined in
> your schema and line up with what your documents look like in MongoDB.
> Although you can add instance methods to your document interface, we
> do not recommend doing so.

For more information, please reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html#using-extends-document

And It seems that we can use mongoose sub documents for this requirement. For more information regarding the sub documents, please reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#subdocuments

So in this case, we can rephrase your code a little bit:

Interfaces:

```
export default interface ICars {
   a_class: BrandList[],
}

// The other interfaces can be kept
```

Schema:

```
const Exterior = new Schema({
   // own fields
});


const Interior = new Schema({
   // own fields
});

const Performance = new Schema({
   // own fields
});

const Volume = new Schema({
   // own fields
});

const SpecsSchema = new Schema({
   // own fields
});

const BrandListSchema = new Schema({
  // other fields
  engine_specs: [SpecsSchema],
  volume_weights: [VolumeSchema],
  performance: [PerformanceSchema],
  images_interior: [InteriorSchema],
  images_exterior: [ExteriorSchema],
});

const CarsSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  a_class: [BrandListSchema],
});
```

Comment: still not getting the API to work, i hope there is not problem with schema

Comment: Could you please more specific on the error or the problem that you got with this approach @mura1?